# Multiple files Drag and Drop window for Applescript

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, applescript, applescript-objc

I have developed an Applescript code which does the following:

• Go through a folder

• Get all .docs/.xls/.ppt/.pdf

• Question the user stuff like: "Which slides to include from .ppt?", "Which sheets to include from .xls?", "Which pages from the .doc?", "Which pages from the .pdf?"

• Get all requested doc pages, xls sheets, ppt slides, pdf pages

• Convert them all to .pdf

• Create a PDF-report with all requested items after each other

The Script is running properly, but in order to make it more practical (so far I have implemented it as an Automator service), I want to create a UI as follows:

• Window where you can add files by drag n drop

• Buttons with which you can move files up and down in the list and thus determine their position in the final PDF-report

I have no experience with Xcode, Objective C or Cocoa. Which is the easiest way to realize this?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you at least show some AppleScript?

Comment: on run {input, parameters}
 
 set loc to (the path to desktop folder as text)
 tell application "Finder"
  make new folder at loc with properties {name:"Temp"}
  set outputDirectory to the result as text
 end tell
 log outputDirectory
 
 display dialog "Namen für die Ergebnisdatei eingeben: " default answer ""
 set theName to text returned of the result
 set outputFile to (the path to desktop folder as text) & theName & ".pdf"
 
 
 tell application "Microsoft Word"
  
  repeat with x in input

Comment: and so on... just to give you an impression of how I get the input and of the loop...

Comment: the basic idea is to have an application that you can drag all kinds of MS files + PDF-files into, which then creates a aggregating PDF-report on the selected parts of these.

Comment: I'm assuming you'd much rather find a widget (like a list box, etc.) than use the "droppable app" feature (where you can drop multiples items onto the app's icon).